# change row values if one field has a NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to change the null values in woonplaats to: "totaal van deze regio" and when that is filled in woonplaats, the NULL value in maand should be the same. but when the woonplaats is filled in, and only the value in maand IS NULL. then the value in maand has to be: "de totale omzet van deze woonplaats

I have a table which looks like this:
[image]

This is my query

```
select v.regiocode, woonplaats, month(besteldatum) as maand, 
       '€ ' + cast(sum(prijs*aantal) as varchar) as omzet
from   klant k
  join verkoopregio v
    on left(k.postcodehuisnr,4) between v.pcbegin and v.pceinde
  join bestelling be
    on k.klantnr = be.klantnr
  join bestelregel br
    on be.bestelnr = br.bestelnr
  left join artikelprijs ap
    on br.artikelnr = ap.artikelnr
    and year(be.besteldatum) = 2014 
    and be.besteldatum between ap.begindatum and ap.einddatum
  group by v.regiocode,woonplaats, month(besteldatum)
  with rollup
```

The outcome of the query:
[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear to us if you add your desired outcome to your question

Comment: If there are 2 null values next to each other, set them both to "totale omzet van deze regio". But when its only one null value in maand it has to be "totale omzet van deze woonplaats

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command:

```
update name-of-table
   set maand='some value' 
 where woonplaats = 'totaal van deze regio'
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP wants, but with the info he has given this answer is correct

Comment: @GuidoG I thought the same, looks so simple, can be missing something, or not :)

Comment: this is from a select statement. i'm using the ROLLUP function. But it returns null values. i want to change these values.

Comment: @MFox could you add your `select` statement to the question?

Comment: @MFox Yes add it to the question and elaborate a bit more what you want

Comment: done that now, i want to change the null values in woonplaats to: "totaal van deze regio" and when that is filled in woonplaats, the NULL value in maand should be the same. 

but when the woonplaats is filled in, and only the value in maand IS NULL. then the value in maand has to be: "de totale omzet van deze woonplaats"

Comment: @MFox This is your question, why dont you edit your question again and put this question in there. The readers have to find you question in there, not in the comments

Comment: Your second table is more confusing!!

Comment: @Amazigh.Ca What second table ? The second picture is the outcome of his query not a table. Unfortunate he has not provided us with his desired outcome

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the table name when it meet your condition
set maand=your value
where condition

```
update tablename
set maand='desired value'
where woonplaats= 'totaal van deze regio'
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP wants, but with the info he has given this answer is correct

Comment: You are updating maand, did you see that maand is not a column name?, it's just an alias in here select query!!!

Comment: @Amazigh.Ca That is correct now, but at the time he wrote the answer all this information was not present in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you want to do the following:

If woonplaats is null, it should be updated to `totaal van deze regio`, however, when woonplaats has a value, this should be updated to Maand with the same value, should Maand be Null.

Herewith is a proposed solution, however, if your `Maand` field is an integer, it would not work. Then I need you to provide me with more detail on the table, etc.

```
select v.regiocode, isnull(woonplaats,'totaal van deze regio'), isnull(month(besteldatum),woonplaats) as maand, 
       '€ ' + cast(sum(prijs*aantal) as varchar) as omzet
from   klant k
  join verkoopregio v
    on left(k.postcodehuisnr,4) between v.pcbegin and v.pceinde
  join bestelling be
    on k.klantnr = be.klantnr
  join bestelregel br
    on be.bestelnr = br.bestelnr
  left join artikelprijs ap
    on br.artikelnr = ap.artikelnr
    and year(be.besteldatum) = 2014 
    and be.besteldatum between ap.begindatum and ap.einddatum
  group by v.regiocode,woonplaats, month(besteldatum)
  with rollup
```

The above is the select query, however, if you want to update these values, kindly advise if you want me to provide you with the update query?